# Restangular ResponseInterceptor for loading state gives an error

Tags: angularjs, restangular

**I have this code in my controller (I do an ng-repeat in the view) :**

```
$scope.projects = Restangular.all('projects').getList().$object;
```

**And then I have this object that get's returned from a mongolab API**

```
[
    {
        _id: { "$oid" : "546a3bdee4b0bfd97138fe08"},
        "picture" : "http://placehold.it/400x400" , 
        "name" : "Square Campus" ,  
        "address" : "293 Grafton Street, Shasta, Arizona, 6757" , 
        "phone" : "+1 (916) 544-2274" , 
        "buildings" : [ 
            { "name" : "North Campus" , "floors" : "4" , "users" : "8"} , 
            { "name" : "South Campus" , "floors" : "2" , "users" : "15"} , 
            { "name" : "East Wing" , "floors" : "8" , "users" : "23"}
        ]
    },
    {
        ... // Other project
    },
    {
        ... // Other project
    }
]
```

Now, this works fine by itself, I can get the data to display in the view. But I'm trying to add a RequestInterceptor and ResponseInterceptor to add a loading spinner when the data loads.

**Adding this:**

```
        RestangularProvider.addRequestInterceptor(function () {
            console.log('loading data');
        });

        RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function () {
            console.log('loaded data');
        });
```

**Causes the following error :**

```
Error: Response for getList SHOULD be an array and not an object or something else
```

**I have a similar problem in the detail page when I try to access the buildings :**

```
    var detailProject = Restangular.one('projects', $routeParams.projectId);
    detailProject.get().then(function (project) {
            $scope.project = project;

            project.buildingTotals = _.reduce(project.buildings,
              function (sums, building) {
                  return {
                      floors: sums.floors + parseInt(building.floors),
                  };
              },
              { floors: 0 }
            );
        });
```

**API Return :**

```
{ 
    "_id" : { "$oid" : "546a3bdee4b0bfd97138fe08"} , 
    "picture" : "http://placehold.it/400x400" , 
    "name" : "Square Campus" ,  
    "address" : "293 Grafton Street, Shasta, Arizona, 6757" , 
    "phone" : "+1 (916) 544-2274" , 
    "buildings" : [ 
        { "name" : "North Campus" , "floors" : "4" , "users" : "8"} , 
        { "name" : "South Campus" , "floors" : "2" , "users" : "15"} , 
        { "name" : "East Wing" , "floors" : "8" , "users" : "23"}
    ]
}
```

**Gives the following error:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'buildings' of undefined
```

Please note that this doesn't happen if the ResponseInterceptor isn't present in the config.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? I think I'm specifying that each return should be an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to return values from your interceptors.

```
var pendingRequests = 0;

RestangularProvider.addRequestInterceptor(
    function (element, operation, what, url) {
        if (pendingRequests == 0) {
            console.log('loading data (show indicator)');
        }
        pendingRequests++;
        return element;
    });

RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(
    function (data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
        pendingRequests--;
        if (pendingRequests == 0) {
            console.log('loaded data (hide indicator)');
        }
        return data;
    });

RestangularProvider.addErrorInterceptor(
    function(response, deferred, responseHandler) {
        pendingRequests--;
        if (pendingRequests == 0) {
            console.log('loaded data (hide indicator)');
        }
        return true; // error not handled
    });
```

See the documentation for more information:

- [addRequestInterceptor()](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#addrequestinterceptor)
- [addResponseInterceptor()](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#addresponseinterceptor)

Comment: Thank you so much... forgot to read : "It's a function that must return the element to be requested"